# Use case identification for system

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have to create Use Case Diagram for Pizza Shop System.

I have doubts whether I fully understand the use case assumption.

1. Are logging into the system, logging in as an administrator or
   creating a new account a use case?
2. Are the details of the payment method (card or cash) / delivery use
   case?

[MY USE CASE DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoADp.jpg):
[image]

Comment: This is not a use case diagram. This is a derailed functional decomposition of the needs. More explanations here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/432766/209774

Comment: @Christophe I'd upvote over there but I left that community once I recognized they are too code-centric.